# Array of hashes to hash of hash

Tags: ruby

How can I transform an array of hashes `response`:

```
response = [
  {id: 1, name: 'foo', something: {}},
  {id: 2, name: 'bar', something: {}}
]
```

where the `:id`s are unique, to a hash of hashes `transformed` with values as the elements of `response` and the key as the corresponding `:id` value turned into a string as follows?

```
transformed = {
  '1' => {id: 1, name: 'foo', something: {}},
  '2' => {id: 2, name: 'bar', something: {}}
}
```

Comment: Can you add your desired output ? you want to keep `id` in transformed hash or as a key ?

Comment: "How can I transform the response (i.e array of hashes) to, a hash of hash …" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Even though you may find correct answers to your question within minutes of asking it, I would recommend waiting for a few hours (ideally 24 hours) before you mark an answer as accepted. Questions with already accepted answers revert a lot of users from posting different (and sometimes even better) approaches to do the same task.

Answer (score 3):

Since **`ruby 2.4.0`** you can use native **[`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)** method:

```
response
.group_by{|h| h[:id]}
.transform_keys(&:to_s)
.transform_values(&:first)
# => {
#      "1"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}},
#      "2"=>{:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}
#    }
```

Comment: I just noticed the question is tagged `ruby` and there is no method `transform_values` on Hash in ruby.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh There is such method in plain Ruby.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh [`Hash#transform_values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) was introduced in Ruby 2.4, along with [`Hash#compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-compact) (and their bang variants)

Comment: Great. I guess I had the lower version installed.

Comment: @sawa : i have make an update to your answer to inform about supporting version of ruby for your solution. 1+ for `Hash#transform_values`

Answer (score 3):

other options

```
response.map{ |i| [i[:id].to_s, i] }.to_h
#=> {"1"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}}, "2"=>{:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}}

Hash[response.map{ |i| [i[:id].to_s, i] }]
#=> {"1"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}}, "2"=>{:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}

response.inject({}) { |h, i| h[i[:id].to_s] = i; h }
#=> {"1"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}}, "2"=>{:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}}
```

@Stefan's solution

```
response.each.with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i[:id].to_s] = i }
#=> {"1"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}}, "2"=>{:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}}
```

@engineersmnky's solution

```
response.inject({}) {|h,i| h.merge({i[:id].to_s => i})} 
#=> {"1"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}}, "2"=>{:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}}
```

Comment: the inject solution is a bit obtuse maybe `inject({}) {|h,i| h.merge({i[:id].to_s => i})}` so that we don't need the semicolon.

Comment: If you're not interested in the block's result and just want to modify the memo object, then `each_with_object` is a better fit: `response.each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i[:id].to_s] = i }`

Comment: @engineersmnky another solution to avoid semicolon would be `response.inject({}) { |h, i| h.tap{|hh| hh[i[:id].to_s] = i } }`

Answer (score 1):

```
response = [{ id: 1, name: 'foo', something: {} },{ id: 2, name: 'bar', something: { } }]    
hash = Hash.new    
response.each {|a| hash[a[:id].to_s] = a }
puts hash
```

Comment: This is not the output OP wants.

Comment: It should be `puts hash`, the `transformed` variable isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you will have the `id` as key in resulting hash, there is no need to keep it in the value again. See my solution using [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) (with `id` removed from value):

```
input
 => [{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}},
     {:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}]

input.each_with_object({}) do |hash, out|
  out[hash.delete(:id).to_s] = hash
end
 => {"1"=>{:name=>"foo", :something=>{}},
     "2"=>{:name=>"bar", :something=>{}}}
```

**Note:** It will modify the `input` array permanently.

However, to have the exact output as mentioned in the question, do:

```
input.each_with_object({}) do |hash, out|
  out[hash[:id].to_s] = hash
end
 => {"1"=>{:id=>1, :name=>"foo", :something=>{}},
     "2"=>{:id=>2, :name=>"bar", :something=>{}}}
```

Comment: This is not the output OP wants.

Comment: Just saw it. Thanks.